# Accessing RPC caller's IP and HTTP connect headers inside ApplicationSession's registered endpoint

Tags: python, autobahn, python-asyncio

I'm using Autobahn 0.9.2 with Python 3.4 with asyncio.

**Questions:** Using WAMP, is it possible to access the peer acting as a Caller's IP and HTTP connection header from inside an RPC endpoint? Is this information persisted when a connection is established? If not, how would I get started extending some factories to support this?

My objective is rather simple: I want to have an RPC endpoint to Geolocalize the IP of the connected peer (the Caller) and relay the augmented data to Redis. I have read the source and know where the information passes through (autobahn.websocket.protocol.WebSocketServerProtocol -> onConnect(request)) but am having trouble drilling down to it from the ApplicationSession's RPC endpoint defined in the onJoin callback. I tried traversing the transport/router/router session chain and didn't manage to get there. I'm interested in both the Peer's IP and the HTTP headers from the initial connection request.

Here's the distilled Component:

```
class IncomingComponent(ApplicationSession):

def __init__(self, **params):
    super().__init__()
    self.redis = StrictRedis(host=config["redis"]["host"], port=config["redis"]["port"], db=config["redis"]["databases"]["ailytics"])

def onConnect(self):
    self.join("abc")

@asyncio.coroutine
def onJoin(self, details):

    def geolocalize_and_store_event(event, detail):
        # Geolocalize here! Have access to caller ID through detail
        self.redis.rpush("abc:events", json.dumps(event))

    yield from self.register(
        geolocalize_and_store_event,
        "abc.geolocalize_and_store_event",
        options=RegisterOptions(details_arg='detail', discloseCaller = True)
    )
```

And the initialization of the server:

```
    router_factory = wamp.RouterFactory()

    session_factory = wamp.RouterSessionFactory(router_factory)
    session_factory.add(IncomingComponent())

    transport_factory = websocket.WampWebSocketServerFactory(session_factory, debug=False, debug_wamp=False)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(transport_factory, '0.0.0.0', 7788)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.close()
```

Comment: Not yet there .. but s.o. already asked for it: https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/issues/142

Comment: Thanks for replying. Managed to find a temporary solution as highlighted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access extra session/transport information via the `wamp.session.get` meta-API in crossbar.io at least:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def onJoin(self, ign):

    @inlineCallbacks
    def method(details):
        session = yield self.call('wamp.session.get', details.caller)
        peer = session['transport']['peer']
        print "peer's address", peer

        headers = session['transport']['http_headers_received']
        print "headers:"
        print '\n'.join(['{}: {}'.format(k, v) for (k, v) in headers.items()])

    yield self.register(
        method, 'some_method',
        types.RegisterOptions(details_arg='details'),
    )
```

Comment: This is now the proper way of doing this as of this date. Marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Also remember your Crossbar instance must be configured to disclose the caller, otherwise you will see `None` in the `details.caller` field.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality isn't there yet as stated by @oberstet, but thanks to the autobahn/WAMP stuff  using the factory pattern, I was able to come up with a solution without changing the library's code.

**There are 3 components to subclass:**

First, we add an ipAddress instance variable to wamp.RouterSession's subclass

```
class IncomingServerSession(wamp.RouterSession):

    def __init__(self, routerFactory):
        super().__init__(routerFactory)
        self.ipAddress = None
```

Then we make the wamp.RouterSessionFactory subclass use IncomingServerSession

```
class IncomingServerSessionFactory(wamp.RouterSessionFactory):
    session = IncomingServerSession
```

Finally, we subclass websocket.WampWebSocketServerProtocol and set the ipAddress instance variable. Since we are in the onOpen callback, we have access to the peer and HTTP headers. My server is reverse-proxied so I'm looking for a custom HTTP header over the peer.

```
class IncomingServerProtocol(websocket.WampWebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onOpen(self):
        try:
            self._session = self.factory._factory()

            # Use your own header or just the peer if not reverse-proxied
            self._session.ipAddress = (self.http_headers.get('x-real-ip') or self.peer) 

            self._session.onOpen(self)

        except Exception as e:
            if self.factory.debug_wamp:
                traceback.print_exc()
                # # Exceptions raised in onOpen are fatal ..
                reason = "WAMP Internal Error ({})".format(e)
                self._bailout(protocol.WebSocketProtocol.CLOSE_STATUS_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR, reason=reason)
```

**Here's how we access the peer's IP inside an RPC call:**

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def onJoin(self, details):
    def event(e, details):
        caller_session_id = details.caller
        caller_session = self._transport._router._dealer._session_id_to_session[caller_session_id]

        print(caller_session.ipAddress)

    #discloseCaller needs to be True
    yield from self.register(event, "abc.event", options=RegisterOptions(details_arg='details', discloseCaller=True))
```

**Finally we need to update our initialization code to use our subclasses:**

```
router_factory = wamp.RouterFactory()

session_factory = IncomingServerSessionFactory(router_factory)
session_factory.add(IncomingComponent())

transport_factory = websocket.WampWebSocketServerFactory(session_factory, debug=False, debug_wamp=False)
transport_factory.protocol = IncomingServerProtocol

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(transport_factory, '0.0.0.0', 7788)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    server.close()
    loop.close()
```

**That's how you do it until official support is there!**

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer for now and will change it once official support is there in the WAMP protocol.

Comment: ;) I see you've found your way through the internals. I've backlinked from the Crossbar.io issue to this, so we can update later for "official" way. Thx for caring and informing readers about the latter btw!